# What am I doing wrong in my code python that it won't print the totall cost?

Tags: python, scripting

This code needs to allow up to 3 inputs for items wanted and print a total cost of all the items. I am VERY new to all this and need all the advice I can get. I can not get the total to print out.

```
pie = 2.75
coffee = 1.50
icecream = 2.00

while choice:

    choice01 = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")

    if choice01 == "nothing":
        break

    choice02 = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")

    if choice02 == "nothing":
        break

    choice03 = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")

    if choice03 == "nothing":
        break

    cost = choice01+choice02+choice03


    print "Your total is: ${0}" .format(cost)
```

Comment: "pie" is different from the variable `pie`

Comment: In addition to Andy's comment: `raw_input` returns a string. It doesn't magically map to a variable that happens to have that name. You need to do that mapping (using e.g. a dict).

Comment: actually `cost = choice01+choice02+choice03` is not adding prices, rather it is doing `"pie" + "nothing" + "coffee"`

Answer (score 3):

Let's focus on what your code is doing.

```
choice01 = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")
```

When the user answers this question, their answer is a string. It is now in `choice01`. For this example, let's assume they type "pie" (no quotes).

We repeat this with the `choice02 =` line and the user selects "coffee".

Let's look at your `cost =` line with just these two choices.

```
cost = choice01 + choice02
```

We just determined that `choice01` is the string value "pie" and `choice02` is the string value "coffee" Thus, `cost = "piecoffee"`

---

#### How do you fix this?

You want to utilize those variables at the top. One way to do this is to create a dictionary:

```
prices = {"pie": 2.75,
    "coffee": 1.50,
    "icecream": 2.00,
    "nothing": 0.00
}

...

cost = prices[choice01]+prices[choice02]+prices[choice03]
```

---

#### What did I do?

In the dictionary, I set up your 4 possible values and associated prices. "nothing" has a value of 0.00, because you utilize that in your cost calculation. It makes the math easy and it works because you are assuming there will always be 3 choices made.

It is important to note that with this method, if the user typos their answer (ie. "cofee" instead of "coffee"), it will throw an exception. It's an activity for you to determine how you want to handle such an error. There are various points you could add such a check.

---

#### Other fixes

There are a few other things you need to fix:

- `while choice:` isn't going to work as your code stands. You don't define `choice`. An alternative is to simply do `while True` and then at the end of your loop break out.
- You can compress the entire input loop to only a simple ask and add to a running total. This would allow you to take more than 3 choices.

Example:

```
prices = {"pie": 2.75,
        "coffee": 1.50,
        "icecream": 2.00
    }

cost = 0.00
while True:
    choice = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")
    if choice == "nothing":
        break
    cost = cost + prices[choice]

print "Your total is: ${0}" .format(cost)
```

Outputs:

```
What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing? pie
What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing? nothing
Your total is: $2.75
```

Notice that we only have the user input question once and we define `cost` before the start of our loop. Then we just add to that each time through the loop. I also removed the "nothing" key from the dictionary, because you break out of the loop prior to adding the selection to the cost.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check the input which maybe out of your choices
2. You use undefined variables: *choice*, *cost*

`price_dict = dict(
        pie=2.75,
        coffee=1.50,
        icecream=2.00,
        nothing=None)`

```
max_choices = 3
cost = 0

while max_choices:
    choice = raw_input(
        "What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")
    # please check the input
    if choice not in price_dict:
        print 'Your input is invalid, please enter again...'
        continue
    if choice == 'nothing':
        break
    max_choices -= 1
    cost += price_dict[choice]

print "Your total is: ${0}" .format(cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you define at the top are variable names for pie, coffee and ice cream.

What you get from raw_input are strings of text.

They don't match up just by being the same, you have to match them up somehow. I suggest more like:

```
pie = 2.75
coffee = 1.50
icecream = 2.00
cost = 0

while True:

    choice = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")

    if choice == "nothing":
        break
    if choice == "pie":
        cost = cost + pie
    if choice = "coffee":
        cost = cost + coffee

        #... etc.

print "Your total is: ${0}".format(cost)
```

And if you want to avoid lots of `if` statements, look at @Evert's suggestion of a dictionary holding the prices.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need three choices at all. consider the following code

```
pie = 2.75
coffee = 1.50
icecream = 2.00
cost = 0
while True:
    choice01 = 0
    choice01 = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")

    if choice01 == "nothing":
        break
    elif choice01=="coffee":
        choice01 = coffee
    elif choice01=="pie":
        choice01 = pie
    elif choice01=="icecream":
        choice01==icecream
    else:
        choice01=0
    cost+=choice01

print "Your total is: ${0}" .format(cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that user enter only pie and not "pie" because Python will take "pie" as a string.
2. Consider using dictionary:- `choices = {'pie' : 2.75, 'coffee':1.50, 'icecream': 2.00, 'nothing':0}` and then use for loop. You can use file loop also, but it is advisable to use simpler loop if not necessary otherwise.
3. Also declare `cost= 0` just before starting loop. Here's the loop:-

   ```
   for x in range(0, 3):
       choosed = raw_input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")
       cost = cost + choices[choosed]
   ```

   And then at last (outside loop) user `print "Your total is: ${0}" .format(cost)`  to get total amount.

Putting up all this together:-

```
choices = {'pie' :2.75, 'coffee':1.50, 'icecream': 2.00, 'nothing': 0}
cost = 0
for x in range(0, 3):
        choosed = input("What would you like to buy? pie, coffee, icecream, or nothing?")
        cost = cost + choices[choosed]
print "Your total is: ${0}" .format(cost)
```

P.S.:- I'd advice rather than asking input 3 times, stop asking once user enters EOF. For that you can consider `if choosed == "nothing": break`